# Проблема с решением задач на codewars

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

У меня проблема с решением задач на codewars. Не могу решать задачи меньше, чем 7 кю. Вроде все темы по js понимаю, но не могу найти алгоритм на первый взгляд простой задачи. Нет мышления для выполнения задач. Как можно это "ликвидировать". Есть ещё 1 вопрос какой уровень "кю" нужно уметь решать junior, middle, senior.

Comment: Берёте любую задачу, того же 6 уровня и просто пишите псевдокод. Пишите максимально неоптимизировано, но понятно для себя, шаг за шагом. Например [задача](https://www.codewars.com/kata/523a86aa4230ebb5420001e1) - найти анаграммы. Ну и думаете как можно проверить, что две строки содержат одинаковые буквы. Первый вариант пройтись по каждой букве в каждом слове и посчитать их кол-во. После того как вы сделаете это, подумаете: "Ага... выглядит не очень" и придумаете отсортировать строку (как массив) и сравнить два слова.. Вот, короче не бойтесь писать плохой код.. Если 7 уровень делаете...

Comment: то 5 тем более сделаете, потому что 5 это по сути несколько 7)))

Comment: Из 6 кю пока смог только её осилить https://www.codewars.com/kata/5526fc09a1bbd946250002dc/train/javascript
Вот таким плохим способом
function findOutlier(integers) {
        let a = integers.filter((num) => num % 2 === 0)
        let b = integers.filter((num) => {
            if (num < 0) {
                return num % 2 === -1
            }
            return num % 2 === 1
        })
        return a.length === 1 ? a[0] : b[0]
    }

Comment: Сам чуть-чуть озадачился)) `function findOutlier(integer) {
    const arr=integer.reduce((a,c)=>(a[Math.abs(c)%2+2]+=1,a[Math.abs(c)%2]=c,a),[0,0,0,0]);
    return arr[2] > arr[3] ? arr[1] : arr[0];
}`

Comment: Либо еще и так `function findOutlier(integer) {
    const arr = integer.sort((a,b)=>Math.abs(a)%2-Math.abs(b)%2);
    return Math.abs(arr[0])%2==0 && Math.abs(arr[1])%2 == 0 ? arr[arr.length - 1] : arr[0];
}`

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь получить ответ на непростой вопрос хотя как вам кажется он очевидно простым. Начнем по порядку. Как ликвидировать - терпение и труд. Вам необходимо решать побольше задач начиная от простых вещей по типу сложить разделить присвоить поменять, дабы все отложилось в памяти. Затем задачи по сложнее, иначе никак. Это по типу вы хотите обучить ребенка писать стихи, а он понятие не имеет о чем это вы. Соответственно чтоб узнать его уровень вы будите упрощать вплоть до букв. Тут также если вам не понятен уровень спускайтесь на уровень меньше .... По поводу уровня для решения задач, это чисто субъективно. Вы можете классно решать задачи по меркам одного и совсем ничего по меркам другого.